# How to run npm start for reactjs even after closing terminal?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've been following facebook tutorial with reactjs

I installed `npm install -g create-react-app` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts and created the app with it

But now I'm confuse how do I deploy my app to, for example, digital ocean? I know I can use `pm2` to run a node server but I don't see how does `npm start` works as it just runs this in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.8",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

`"start": "react-scripts start"` what is it actually starting there?

also, it says that to build your app for deployment to use `npm run build` that just gives me a folder named `build` but I can't find anything to run `node` on.

Comment: Have you had a chance to read the User Guide? I believe it answers all your questions. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend reading the [User Guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md) as it answers many common questions.

`npm start` starts the development server. It's only useful for development so you should never use it in production. This is printed in its output.

`npm run build` produces a static `build` folder with HTML, CSS, and JS files. You don't need Node to run it. It is static. To serve it, you would need to use any static file server. You can do this with Node, Python, Nginx, or any file server that can serve static files. This should also be printed in the command's output.

The deployment instructions vary depending on your hosting provider but basically you need to serve the `build` output from the server root, and you're set. If you use client-side routing you'll also want to configure your web server to serve `index.html` as a fallback for any path.

The user guide includes specific deployment instructions for different providers so check it out.

Comment: @Johhan How did you got it,would you please share the process, how to get it working, I am also having the same problem ,building the app is fine,need to run without port

Comment: Hey @VenkateshSomu just run `npm run build` it will create a build folder where you can copy paste the files from inside it and put them in a server like godaddy or for localhost xampp htdocs folder.

Comment: @Johhan , The npm run build is working fine after copying the build folder and run it using localhost,the home page is working fine but the routings is not working like showing 404 not found pages.If i use hashHistory instead of browserHistory the rouging is working fine with additional displaying of /# in all of the routing urls.

Comment: @VenkateshSomu If I recall, this is a known bug, try adding the files in the root of the htdocs folder instead of using a subfolder, eg: localhost/subfolder